# Algorithm to verify that all the "1" in a two-dimensional Array build a rectangle

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

> Define a method that, given a two-dimensional Array of Integers, verifies that all the elements equals to 1 build a rectangle.

[image: An Image so you can understand better]

This is what I came up with until now:

```
public static boolean oneRectangle(int [][] a) {
    boolean rectangle=true;
    int[][] res;
    int OneinRow=0; //keeps track of how many ones there are in the row
    int OneinColoumn=0; //keeps track of how many ones there are in a coloumn

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
            while (a[i][j] == 1) {
                i++;
                OneinRow++;
            }
            while (a[i][j] == 1) {
                j++;
                OneinColoumn++;
            }
        }
    }
    res = new int[OneinRow][OneinColoumn];

    for(int k=0; k<res.length; k++)
        for(int l=0; l<res[0].length; l++)
            if(res[k][l] != 1)
                rectangle = false;

    return rectangle;
}
```

it doesn't work as expected, because for

```
f = new int[][] {
            {1,2,3,4}, //1 in position 0
            {2,1,4,5}, //1 in position 1
            {3,4,5,6}};
```

returns `true` instead of `false`.

How can I fix and improve the algorithm?

Comment: Note, `res` table contains only zeros after creation and you don't fill it with anything alse

Comment: Try explain yourself (and us) the algorithm your are trying to implement.

Comment: @krzydyn thanks it's true there is nothing in the res array, I'll fix it

Comment: Your algorithm is not correct, even your code is written recklessly. You are counting the number of 1 in the column but which column??

Comment: @Prince that's true too... I may have to come up with a totally different algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counting the 1s per row and column is not enough.

I do it this way:

Loop over the whole array and keep track of the highest and lowest index in each dimension where a 1 occurred. In addition count all the 1s seen.

At the end the number of 1s must be the same as the product of the difference of highest and lowest index for each dimension.

For a 2D array:

```
int minx=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxx=-1;
int miny=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxy=-1;
int count=0;
for x=0...
  for y=0...
    if(1==a[x][y]{
      minx=Math.min(minx,x);
      maxx=Math.max(maxx,x);
      miny=Math.min(miny,y);
      maxy=Math.max(maxy,y);
      count ++;
    }

return count==(maxx-minx+1)*(maxy-miny+1);
```

P.s. You might want to add a check if there was at least one 1.

Comment: You can also do it in a single pass if you are willing to keep a more complicated state.

Comment: @Sorin: It is in one pass. See the pseudo-code I added.

Comment: @MrSmith42 could you explain me how exactly the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` works? I've never used it before.

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE is equal to 2,147,483,648

Comment: @Prince and what is it's purpose in the code... I don't get it. why should I use such a high integer as the minimum value of x and y?

Comment: Because first time, minx = y; as whatever will be the value of  y, it won't be greater that MAX_VALUE